# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when ascribing a value to an array index

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, data-science

Why is the compiler giving me a **ValueError** on the last line?

```
 # Get coefficiants
    theta = np.array([0,0], dtype = float)
    
    theta[1] = get_covariance(x, x_mean, y, y_mean) / get_variance(x, x_mean)
    theta[0] = y - theta[1] * x
```

Comment: What are `x` and `y`?

Comment: @sagi x and y are columns of a dataset.

Comment: @sagi also both columns are numerical.

Comment: `theta[0]` is a float, the result of `y - theta[1] * x` is an array, what do you expect to happen here?

Comment: @sagi I want to get coefficiants for a linear regression.

Comment: @sagi okay, I got the problem, I coded the formula wrong, thanks for the help!